# SVN Commit Error (couldn't perform atomic operation)

Tags: svn, ubuntu, projectlocker

Everything was working fine, when all of a sudden, I am getting a

```
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Couldn't perform atomic initialization
```

What could the problem be ?

I am using "projectlocker" (http://projectlocker.com/)

OS: Ubuntu10.04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Weird, it started working fine, after about 15 mins.

I did not do anything.

Comment: Started working after 15 minutes?  Your "asked" and "answered" times are only a minute apart.

Comment: @BenBarden, he said 15 minutes to make his answer more statistically likely of being right, lol.

Comment: @BenBarden it took him 14 minutes to log into SO and write the question

Comment: @BenBarden, Matrixugly, johnyycardy :) Hehhehe Yes, it was a white ago - don't remember if it took me 14 minutes to get onto SO. Or I just lied :)

Comment: This is not an answer. One of the common reasons that this exception is being thrown is when the svn server or the local machine have no disk-space left.

Answer (score 23):

In my case, it was because the partition that svn had been installed in, was full.

Comment: This was my issue as well. Once I freed-up disk space, the commit worked fine.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the issue!

Comment: I faced the same issue,  In my case, The root folder '/' was full in the svn server.

Comment: this works, our server was full

Answer (score 14):

**Make sure there is space on your SVN Server's hard drive partition!**

I noticed the same behavior. Wait a couple minutes then it worked. But that didn't always fix the problem. After looking at our SVN server we found that one of the partitions (the one that the server was on) was chalk full.

I had our IT guy clean up some of the space and everything worked nice and slick after that.

Comment: My "partition full" answer was first! :D

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the similar issue.

Cause - file system became read only.
fix - reboot the server

Comment: I had the same issue.  In my case, the reason it became read-only was that it ran out of space on the hard drive, so the fix was a bit more involved, but still essentially the same cause.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was caused by the fact that apache was loading libphp5 module before mod_dav_svn and mod_authz_svn. The problem is that Apache is loading the implementation of libsqlite included in libphp5. So basically put LoadModule dav_svn_module and LoadModule authz_svn_module before LoadModule php5_module in your httpd.conf. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue.

Had 'PROPPATCH' and 'atomic initialization' issues.

Filesystem was okay..

FIX: restart the apache daemon.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue but mine was because of insufficient access privilege to `/tmp` folder which will be used by svn when creating a commit.

When I exam apache error log `/var/log/apache2/error.log` I saw

`[Thu Aug 16 13:46:39.498037 2018] [:error] [pid 78] [client 172.16.50.6:60010] Couldn't perform atomic initialization  [500, #200029]
[Thu Aug 16 13:46:39.498043 2018] [:error] [pid 78] [client 172.16.50.6:60010] Can't find a temporary directory: Internal error  [500, #20014]`

So if anyone see these logs in your apache server's error log it might be the same reason as mine. After changing my `/tmp` access right to `777` the problem disappears.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I missed the space between 'create' and 'repo path'. I had the error message writing:

```
svnadmin create/repo_path
```

instead of

```
svnadmin create /repo_path
```